# How can I get 'Select Case to test each cell in range?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, case

I don't know how to refer to cells in range so that Case tests each cell in range "animal" I get an error for the line " mammal = Range("animal").Value " it says "Method Range of object _ Global failed" 
And if I cannot directly refer to 'animal' for case select or I will get a mismatch variable error.

```
Dim animal As Range
Set animal = shB.Range("M3:M8")

For Each Cell In animal
Dim mammal As String
mammal = Range("animal").Value

    Select Case mammal
        Case "cat"
            MsgBox "meow"
        Case "dog"
            MsgBox "woof"
    End Select

Next Cell
```

Comment: It should be `mammal = Cell.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for-each` references each object in a collection, which is what a `Range` is.

So each `Cell` refers to a Worksheet cell in the range. Also, multi-cell ranges don't have a single value:

> For ranges whose first area contains more than one cell, Value returns a Variant containing a 2-dimensional array of the values in the individual cells of the first range.

You don't have to declare everything in VBA, and `.value` is the default property of a range;

> The default member of Range forwards calls without parameters to Value. Thus, `someRange = someOtherRange` is equivalent to `someRange.Value = someOtherRange.Value`.

so this works:

```
For Each mammal In Range("A1:C1")

    Select Case mammal
        Case "cat"
            MsgBox "meow"
        Case "dog"
            MsgBox "woof"
    End Select

Next mammal
```

without any other code.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem but now, output is only 'meow' for the 5 terms in the range.